# footer broken in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, navigation, css-float

am facing a strange problem, my very simple footer isn't displaying properly in Firefox. It's basically a display inline nav floated left and a tag floated right. Seems to work fine in every other browser. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="footer_wrap">
<div id="footer_area">

<ul id="footer_nav">

    <li><a href="{site_url}" {if segment_1 == "" OR segment_1 == "view"}class="active"{/if}>Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="{path="/archives"}" {if segment_1 == "archives"}class="active"{/if}>Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="{path="about"}" {if segment_1 == "about"}class="active"{/if}>About</a></li>

</ul>


    <a href="{site_url}" id="footer_logo">&copy; {current_time format="%Y"} {site_name}</a>

<div class="clear"></div>

</div> <!-- end footer area -->
</div> <!-- end footer wrap -->
```

CSS

```
#footer_nav {float: left; list-style: none;}
#footer_nav li {display: inline; margin-right: 20px;}
#footer_nav li a {
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80)";
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-size: 12px;
}
#footer_nav li a:hover {
    font-weight: bold; 
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100)";
}
#footer_nav li a.active {
    font-weight: bold; 
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100)";
}

#footer_logo {
    float: right; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-size: 18px; 
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80)";
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
#footer_logo:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100)";
}
```

Here is the simplified code, the only two validation errors are for empty "height" values on images

```
<div id="footer_wrap">
<div id="footer_area">

<ul id="footer_nav">

    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

</ul>


    <a href="#" id="footer_logo">&copy; 2011 Mysitename</a>

<div class="clear"></div>

</div> <!-- end footer area -->
</div> <!-- end footer wrap -->
```

Good

[image: Chrome - Good]

Bad

[image: Firefox - Bad]

Comment: We'll also need a screenshot or something...

Comment: The actual generated HTML would also be helpful. Browsers behave differently if the markup isn't valid.

Comment: Even better than the screenshot would be, if you can put a simplified example online @ [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - many times making a simplified example will already show the problem and help you to solve it.

Comment: Thanks Andrej, here is the fiddle, looks OK to me even in FF but not on my site http://jsfiddle.net/AsYZ2/2/

Answer (score 0):

(moved from [an edit to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8367359/revisions)):

Finally figured it out guys, it was a rogue bracket instead of a curly brace higher up in my CSS stylesheet which meant everything underneath was not getting seen by firefox or opera